# Is older Raspberry Pi safe? When is the end of software support for them?

Tags: update, security, rpi-update

I am **not** asking about the discontinuation of manufacturing or selling of the hardware; I am talking about **only the software**.

There are famous old Android devices that the manufactures have abandoned a long time ago, but users are providing custom ROM's. As far as I know, even though those come with latest Android security patches, the underlying low-level parts of the software cannot be updated because only the device manufacturers can make them. And I have heard that manufactures like Qualcomm provide such security updates only for a short time.

So, my question is, what about RP? Say, if I buy a cheap used RP 1 or 2, is it still safe? That is, can I get low-level security patches? And if they are, how long can I expect them to get software updates (both low-level software and the operating system)?

Comment: Yes, it's safe. A Pi 1 (I have 1) is considered slow nowadays, but I run Tomcat and a Wiki there, with no problems. In terms of security, just keep it up to date.

Answer (score 6):

The same version of Raspberry Pi OS works on all Pi models.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/

Comment: But lower-level software like, I don't know, drivers or firmware for parts that were made by Broadcom, etc. Do they also get the same treatment?

Comment: Drivers and firmware generally are part of the operating system in Linux.